# Two files include each other in c++ problem

Tags: c++, inclusion

I'm doing some contribution to an open source library, but I'm having trouble modifying other people's code. Previously the library had a file called `IntervalT.h` and a file called `Curves.h` with the implementation in the file `Curves.tcc`, and `Interval.h` includes `Curves.h` for some reason. Right now I need to use `IntervalT.h` in `Curves.h`, but when I tried to use the class `IntervalT<NT>` defined in `IntervalT.h`, the compiler gives me error (I've already included `IntervalT.h` in the beginning of `Curves.h` file):

```
../../../inc/CORE/poly/Curves.h:1337:3: error: ‘IntervalT’ does not name a type
```

My question is: Since I never have had such experience before, is "`does not name a type`" error related to mutual inclusion of c++ header files? Or it is other mistakes that cause this error? If so, how should I write my program to let the Curves.h sees IntervalT.h?

By the way, this piece of code was organized in a very weird way. `Curves.tcc` is actually included by `Curves.h`, which is the reverse way of we usually do. Is there a particular reason to do this? Or it doesn't really matter? And what is `.tcc` extension after all?

Comment: Have you tried declare the type(class or struct whatever) `IntervalT` in `Curves.h` instead of include the `IntervalT.h`?

Comment: What does the line say where this error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess (because you can name your files whatever you want), but the `.tcc` extension is a modification of the `.cc` extension (which is just C++ code) but the `t` stands for `template`. This is confirmed by the fact that `Curves.h` includes `Curves.tcc` which is a common technique for separating the interface from the implementation of a template while still not upsetting the compiler which expects both declaration and definition of templated code in the same file (or you get an error). [See this answer to get a better idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058577/defining-methods-of-class-with-template-parameters/7058610#7058610).

The `does not name a type` could be that `IntervalT` is a template and you're not providing a template parameter (or that could be a different error, I haven't tried it), or that even though the file is called `IntervalT.h` it does not contain a class called `IntervalT`, or that it's in a different namespace. You'll have to give more info before we can make a better diagnosis.